# Filter before inserting to list

Tags: haskell

I've started to learn haskell recently, and I've came across such problem: 
I want to generate list of fibonacci numbers that are only even. I've created recursive function to compute fibonacci numbers, and now I'm trying to insert this numbers into the list 
`[fib x | x <- [1..]]` 
Now let's say I want to put only those computed `fib x` numbers that are less then certain number, eg. `fib x < 92100000` 
I can print this numbers with `filter(<92100000)[fib x | x <- [1..]]`, but the code will still run forever, populating the list. 
How do I finish list insertion, when `fib x` is large enough?

Comment: As a side note: computing each `fib x` in series like that is going to be horribly inefficient. You'd be better off writing a function `fibs` that generates the series as an infinite list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeWhile (<92100000) [fib x | x <- [1..]]` will terminate after reaching the first element that fails the condition, i.e. after the first element greater than or equal to 92100000.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has a fun property about it known as 'laziness', i.e. it only computes whatever values are necessary.

From what I understand, you fear that by doing `takeWhile (<100) [fib x | x <- [1..]]`, first the list comprehention will be evaluated (taking forever), THEN takeWhile (<100) will be applied to it.

This is not the case. You can think of it this way, the list comprehention only calculates and yields values on demand, like so:
[image: Lazy eval]

As opposed to [image: Strict eval]

I hope that makes it pretty clear :D